# Jquery animate, disable animate until complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have the following jQuery script

If you click the div with id twitter it moves to the right and enlarges so that more feeds are shown. The div that already exists on the right gets smaller and moves to the left to fill the place the twitter div was filling in.

```
$('#twitter').click(function() {
if(groot != '#twitter'){
    topv = $("#twitter").css("top");
    $('#twitter').animate({
        left: '475',
        top: '16',
        height: '414' 
    }, 1000, function() {
    });
    $(groot).animate({
        left: '8',
        top: topv,
        height: '128'
    }, 1000, function() {
        groot = '#twitter';
    });
}
});
```

To make things a little bit more clear, I created an image to illustrate what happens when I click on the twitter div.

[image]

This all works fine!

However, when I click on Another small div before the twitter animation is complete, the script behaves very strange, div's overlapping eachother etc...

What is the best method to disable the possibilty to click on another small div before the twitter div animate is complete?

I tried working with variables and stuff, but none of my ideas worked.

EDIT:
Unfortunally none of the given answers worked.
Maybe I did something wrong.
I created a jsfiddle so that you can see the problem and maybe fix it :)

http://jsfiddle.net/ybFha/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a flag that you'll interrogate as to whether or not you want the animation to run upon a click:

```
var isMoving = false;
```

Now adjust your handler a bit to check the flag, which will ensure the animation isn't interrupted by another animation until the first animation is complete.

```
 $('#twitter').click(function() {
 if(isMoving == false){
     isMoving = true;
 if(groot != '#twitter'){
     topv = $("#twitter").css("top");
    $('#twitter').animate({
        left: '475',
        top: '16',
        height: '414' 
    }, 1000, function() {
 });
 $(groot).animate({
    left: '8',
    top: topv,
    height: '128'
 }, 1000, function() {
    groot = '#twitter';
 });
 isMoving = false;
 }
}
});
```

This is untested, I'm working off my netbook on vacation, hopefully this gives you the idea.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunally it didn't work, maybe I did something wrong. Can you please check my JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to leverage the `.data()` method to add a flag on the parent of the elements in question.

Therefore, when any of the click handlers fires, it first checks if the flag is set - if not, set it and start animating. Otherwise, just ignore the click. Once animation is done, reset the flag.

Example (assuming the parent element has the id "box-wrappers")

```
$('#twitter').click(function() {
  if($('#box-wrappers').data('animating')) {
     return;
  }

  $('#box-wrappers').data('animating',1);

  [.. your animation code here ..]

  $('#box-wrappers').data('animating',0);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can add an overall handler to prevent a new animation happening if one is already in progress:

```
if($('.movingBlock:animated').length == 0){
  ... run an animation
}
```

So, if all your blocks to animate are given a class of 'movingBlock', if one is animating, no others will be allowed to animate before the current one has finished.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself

This is my final code.

Looked a lot like Chris Hardie's answer, so he is getting the accept :)

```
$('#twitter').click(function() {
            if(groot != '#twitter'){
                topv = $("#twitter").css("top");
                if(anim != 1){
                    anim = 1;
                    $('#twitter').animate({
                        left: '475',
                        top: '16',
                        height: '414' 
                    }, 1000, function() {
                    });
                    $(groot).animate({
                        left: '8',
                        top: topv,
                        height: '128'
                    }, 1000, function() {
                        groot = '#twitter';
                        anim = 0;
                    });
                }
            }
```

Comment: Good stuff! I would suggest giving your flag a meaningful name for readability's sake, and also to test for `true` or `false` since this is a boolean condition, as 0 and 1 are just magic numbers that confer no meaning.